# What does NoneType actually mean?

Tags: python

I have been making a morse code translator and I have just arrived at a problem with translating  from morse.
Here is my code:

```
def translate(self, message):
    message_words = message.split('   ')
    message_in_morse = ['Your message is: ']
    letters = {'.-':'a', '-...':'b', '-.-.':'c', '-..':'d', '.':'e', '..-.':'f', '--.':'g', '....':'h', '..':'i', '.---':'j', '-.-':'k', '.-..':'l', '--':'m', '-.':'n', '---':'o', '.--.':'p', '--.-':'q', '.-.':'r', '...':'s', '-':'t', '..-':'u', '...-':'v', '.--':'w', '-..-':'x', '-.--':'y', '--..':'z', '.----':'1', '..---':'2', '...--':'3', '....-':'4', '.....':'5', '-....':'6', '--...':'7', '---..':'8', '----.':'9', '-----':'0', '..--..':'?', '.-.-.-':'.', '--..--':',', '   ':' ', ' ':''}
    morse_text = ''
    for letter in message_words:
        message_in_morse.append(letters.get(letter.lower()))
        message_in_morse.append(' ')
    try:
        morse_text = ''.join(message_in_morse)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', str(e))
    return morse_text
```

I am importing it and running `translate('.- .-')`
from another program.
This should output:
`Your message is: aa`
When I run this, it just says:
`Error: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found`
I don't know what this means or how to fix it.

Comment: You're trying to proceed with empty variable.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: `letters.get` returns `None` when the key is not found in the dict, you append it to the list and that's what's causing the exception later.

Comment: Use a default value in case the letter is not found: `message_in_morse.append(letters.get(letter.lower(), ''))` additionally you can get rid of the `try/except` block.

Comment: I tried this  and ran it. It didn't give an error message, but it didn't give any output either, except `Your message is:`

Comment: @Pazzel: Yes. `message.split('   ')` ... there aren't 4 blancs in `message` ...

Answer (score 0):

Your try/except confused me for a while.

Still, I managed to find your typo:

```py
def translate(self, message):
    message_words = message.split(' ')  # split by one space
    message_in_morse = ['Your message is: ']
    letters = {'.-':'a', '-...':'b', '-.-.':'c', '-..':'d', '.':'e', '..-.':'f', '--.':'g', '....':'h', '..':'i', '.---':'j', '-.-':'k', '.-..':'l', '--':'m', '-.':'n', '---':'o', '.--.':'p', '--.-':'q', '.-.':'r', '...':'s', '-':'t', '..-':'u', '...-':'v', '.--':'w', '-..-':'x', '-.--':'y', '--..':'z', '.----':'1', '..---':'2', '...--':'3', '....-':'4', '.....':'5', '-....':'6', '--...':'7', '---..':'8', '----.':'9', '-----':'0', '..--..':'?', '.-.-.-':'.', '--..--':',', '   ':' ', ' ':''}
    morse_text = ''
    for letter in message_words:
        message_in_morse.append(letters.get(letter.lower()))
    try:
        morse_text = ''.join(message_in_morse)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ', str(e))
    return morse_text
print(translate('.- .-'))
```

Output:

```
Your message is: aa
```

Also, you should try to allow for invalid morse:

`message_in_morse.append(letters.get(letter.lower(), '#'))`

This will give `#` for any unknown morse code.

**Update:** removed the extra space between decoded characters.

Comment: This is like a similar comment. It just outputs `Your message is: # ` when I run it with a space in my morse code.

Comment: But that wasn't your question.  You wanted 'a a' as the output and I fixed that problem

Comment: I wanted to translate .- .-, which should give me aa. Now it gives me #

Comment: With my code I get `Your message is: a a`.

Comment: It works for me like that too now, but it should still give `Your message is: aa`, not `Your message is: a a`.

Comment: Ok, but that's what your code was built to do. I'll put in a fix for that too. . . .

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered how to get it to work.
Use nested `for` loops to split the message into words, then each word gets split into separate letters.

```
        message_words = message.split('   ')
        letters_in_message = []
        for word in message_words:
            letters_in_message.append(word.split(' '))
        message_in_morse = ['Your message: ']
        letters = {'.-':'a', '-...':'b', '-.-.':'c', '-..':'d', '.':'e', '..-.':'f', '--.':'g', '....':'h', '..':'i', '.---':'j', '-.-':'k', '.-..':'l', '--':'m', '-.':'n', '---':'o', '.--.':'p', '--.-':'q', '.-.':'r', '...':'s', '-':'t', '..-':'u', '...-':'v', '.--':'w', '-..-':'x', '-.--':'y', '--..':'z', '.----':'1', '..---':'2', '...--':'3', '....-':'4', '.....':'5', '-....':'6', '--...':'7', '---..':'8', '----.':'9', '-----':'0', '..--..':'?', '.-.-.-':'.', '--..--':',', '   ':' ', ';':' '}
        morse_text = ''
        for word in letters_in_message:
            for letter in word:
                message_in_morse.append(letters.get(letter.lower(), '#'))
            message_in_morse.append(' ')
        morse_text = ''.join(message_in_morse)
        return morse_text
```